# Is it possible to test if a specific key is pressed using FreePascal?

Tags: keyboard, freepascal

I would like to be able to write a FreePascal function such as:

```
function KeyIsPressed(ch: char): boolean;
```

which returns true if and only if the key corresponding to the character `ch` is pressed at the time of execution.  This function should allow for constructs such as:

```
if KeyIsPressed('a') and KeyIsPressed('b') and not KeyIsPressed('c') then ...
```

evidently returning true if and only if both 'a' and 'b' are pressed and 'c' is not pressed.

FYI, I am running:

```
Free Pascal Compiler version 3.0.4+dfsg-18ubuntu2 [2018/08/29] for x86_64
Copyright (c) 1993-2017 by Florian Klaempfl and others
```

PS1: I do not care if the keyboard buffer starts filling up or not, a problem one could deal with separately afterwards.

PS2: I did notice similar questions regarding other programing languages, but unfortunately these are of no use for Pascal.

Answer (score 0):

Just look at the implementation of units Crt and/or keyboard. They do those things. But they capture keyboard data from stdin which is already "cooked".

It is hard getting around this. To find out which keyboard combos are hard to make try the "teach keys" functionality of the textmode IDE which basically shows "keyboard" unit functionality

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Indeed unit "keyboard.pp"  seems to read the keyboard via the standard input with the command `fpRead(StdInputHandle,InBuf[InHead],i)`, so it is likely not going to help determining on the spot if a given key is pressed.  Years ago I used to program in Basic, where one could just say `peek(the right memory adddress)` and voilà the answer!  But I guess things are a bit more complicated today, aren't they?

Comment: That's  in old Dos that was effectively single tasking, and supported limited hardware, and lots of tricks to do your own drivers. To be honest I'm happy those days are gone, but the *nix terminal situation is not ideal either.

Comment: detecting keyups and keydowns depend a lot on operating sytem. If you are working in terminal environment fpread will give you keydowns (with repeat reate) until there is keyup. You can maybe use keypressed in main loop to check if key is pressed, read it and ignore if it is not the one you want... as marco said in terminal you should swich to raw mode in order not to wait for enter to be pressed to get your keys from keyboard buffer in terminal with read...